# Liquid Layout, JS solution

Tags: javascript, css, animation, layout

I have a centered liquid layout I am toying with that employs CSS floats.  The main content are equal height/width boxes and when the browser window resizes the css floats reposition.  Is there a simple way utilizing JS/JQuery or similar to animate the movement of the floats when they reposition?

I have explored JQuery Masonry, Isotope and a few others, but I am wondering if there is a simple lightweight method of doing this without figuring the positions of all the boxed with each width change.

Would appreciate any ideas, keywords to search, etc. :)

Comment: Did you checked [JQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) ?

Comment: Yeah, and easing seems like just the module I will need, but how do I implement it without watching all the elements and setting them absolute?

Comment: Honestly, if I could get isotope to center itself on the page reliably I enjoy some of it's features.  Unfortunately, it conflicts with my current centered floats hack and the centered masonry implementation on the site seems to leave the colums with added padding too often for production :(

Comment: Actually it's a very interesting question. Using floats before javascript to ensure liquid layout is a good practice. It would be a pitty to fallback on a full-javascript solution. I'll check it out.

Comment: :)  I did get Masonry to center and work properly, but I would still prefer to only rely on javascript for the animation, progressive enhancement graceful degredation and all that jazz.

Comment: Could you provide an example? So it would be easier to test if a solution meet the needs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21011/discussion-between-charles-edouard-coste-and-samantha-p)

Answer (score 0):

Look at css transitions and animations. You don't need javascript for this.

Comment: Sorry, I have to disagree. Behaviour layer is supposed to be set by javascript, not by CSS. So users may disable it by disactivating javascript in their browser.

By the way... transitions and animations may be applied using css properties. But must be applied by javascript anyway.

Comment: I like the way you were going, unfortunately at the link you specified floats aren't supported yet. [http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/](http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/)

Comment: I promise that if the Samantha posts some code as an example of her situation, I can probably get it working with just css.

Comment: The set-up is just a series of 300px by 300px <li> elements inside of a <ul>.  All of the <li> elements are float:left.  I am trying to make it so that when the browser window is re-sized/zoomed the repositioning of the float to fit the new size is animated/not instant disappear and reappear.  However, graceful degradation is important to me as well.

Comment: Welp, I'll admit when I'm wrong. Been working on this part of the day and have come to the conclusion you really do need at least some basic js to do this effectively.

Comment: :) Well thank you very much for all of the time you've spent.  I do appreciate it very much.  I am starting to come to the same conclusion.  Not only does it seem I need javascript, it seems there is no easy way to tie into the "a float just moved" event.  It seems the only way to do it is relegate the movement to the javascript as well, which means watching browser width and repositioning all of the floats manually..... which equals ouch.  It also, for my meager have-a-script skills, equals a ready-made solution that is much heavier-weight than I initially wanted.